# Show/Hide the Tabs on condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am stuck in the below scenario,

I have list of providers (like INGO, Chexar, Western Union, TSys etc) used by my customer to give various services like sending the money,  bill payment etc.

Now the problem is i am reusing my project for multiple customers. Say CustomerA uses - Western Union, Tsys then Customer B might use - VISA, INGO and so on.

In my UI i have a tab control and i am displaying the provider names as text of the tab but this depends on the customer. So i added all the providers of all Customers as a tab.

So the question here is in my action method i am getting the list of providers say INGO, TSys for CustomerA . Since my UI has all the providers, i need to filter  and display only INGO and TSys tabs.

One solution would be to use flag like -INGO Required and if it is true then add the INGO tab and TsysRequired if this is true add the TSys tab and so on.

But i wanted a generic solution like if a new provider added for the customer i should not change much of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to somehow use flags to indicate the on and off thing for tabs but instead of using boolen variable, use a dictionary object like

```
Dictionay<string,boolean> availableTags = new Dictionay<string,boolean>();
availableTags["INGO"] = true;
availableTags["TSys"] = false;
```

And than you can loop on the dictionary to decide that which tab shall be displayed and which not. In case you have more complex requirement or scenarios than instead of Dictionary u can use List for decisions and manipulations.